# Script to set IP address connected to an interface to a shell variable

Tags: shell, gnome-terminal

I want to write a script to set the IP address of the device connected to an interface like "eth0" to a variable.
I can get the IP address by this command:

```
arp -i eth0 -a
```

The output of above command is:

```
? (10.42.0.38) at b8:27:eb:07:5d:60 [ether] on eth0
```

I want to add a script to `.bashrc` file to set the IP address from output of above command to the variable `$RASPBERRY_IP` and use it in other script.
Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ARP table is not the right source to find your local IP address. Try the `ip` command instead:

```
RASPBERRY_IP=$(ip addr | awk -F"[ /]" '/inet .*eth0/{print $6}')
```

If you want to find another IP address in your network, you can use your ARP table. Try this command:

```
RASPBERRY_IP=$(arp -ai eth0 | cut -d' ' -f2 | sed 's/[()]//g')
```

Note that `$RASPBERRY_IP` will contain more IP addresses if your ARP table contains more entries on eth0! Example: `10.42.0.38 10.42.0.39 10.42.0.40`. Add a `grep` with the raspberry's MAC address. If you only want the first entry, change it to:

```
RASPBERRY_IP=$(arp -ai eth0 | cut -d' ' -f2 | sed 's/[()]//g;q')
```

Don't forget that ARP removes entries from the ARP cache after some time (usually 5 minutes under Unix).

Comment: tnx for your reply, but I don't wanna find my own ip address. I need the ip address of device connected to my device on that network and arp command is for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Variable=$(ip addr | grep inet | grep eth0 | awk -F" " '{print $2}'| sed -e 's/\/.*$//')
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I get this error when I run this command in terminal: `sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unknown option to 's'`

Comment: try this once,

Variable=$(ip addr | grep inet | grep eth0 | awk -F" " '{print $2}'| awk -F '/' '{print $1}')

Comment: I don't want to set my own ip to that variable. I want to set the value of a variable to ip address of the connected device to the network (other than my own device). The `arp` command is for that.

Comment: For it you will need the MAC id of that device that you have connected. And have to use the arp command as follows,

arp -i eth0 -vs <ip> <macId>

Comment: No just `arp -i eth0 -a` will give the ip address and MAC id of the device connected to the network.